# Why Android Compose pass fragment as a parameter to Composables functions?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-compose

I have three compose functions in my fragment.

```
@Composable
fun MessageView(
    action: ApiManagementAction
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_api),
            contentDescription = null,
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.ABCD),
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            fontSize = 14.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.GFHD),
            fontSize = 12.sp,
            color = colorResource(id = R.color.text_secondary),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
        CreateApiButton(action = action, showElevation = false)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        GotoDocument(action = action)
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun CreateApiButton(
    action: ApiManagementAction,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    showElevation: Boolean,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 12.dp),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.title_create_api),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(
                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.color_primary),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
                    )
                    .clickable { action.checkGABeforeEditAndCreate.invoke(null) }
                    .height(45.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    .align(Alignment.TopCenter),
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.black)
            )
        }
    }

}
```

```
@Composable
fun GotoDocument(
    action: ApiManagementAction,
) {

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(45.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 12.dp)
            .clickable {
                action.gotoDocument.invoke()
            }
            .border(
                width = 1.dp,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.divider)
            ),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_api_doc),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(20.dp)
                .width(15.dp)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.title_api_doc),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            fontSize = 12.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(45.dp)
                .wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.CenterVertically)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
        )
    }

}
```

I run compose metric and get this results:

```
restartable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun MessageView(
  stable action: ApiManagementAction
  unstable <this>: ApiManagementFragment
)
restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun CreateApiButton(
  stable action: ApiManagementAction
  stable modifier: Modifier? = @static Companion
  unused stable showElevation: Boolean
  unused unstable <this>: ApiManagementFragment
)
restartable skippable scheme("[androidx.compose.ui.UiComposable]") fun GotoDocument(
  stable action: ApiManagementAction
  unused unstable <this>: ApiManagementFragment
)
```

As you see `MessageView` is **not** `skippable` because of its unstable parameter `ApiManagementFragment`.
Now my question is: Why compose inject my fragment to composable function Even though it is not used?

Comment: "In my Fragment" Do you mean in the same file as the fragment or the Fragment class itself?

Comment: @TheLibrarian inside the fragment and you are right, that's the problem. I should declare  composable functions outside of classes

Comment: To my knowledge @Composables are always top citizens in the file and do not belong to any class. Having this reference to the parent class is probably the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the **Composables** inside the Fragment.

It has an implicit reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `ApiManagementFragment` parameter in the `MessageView` composable is marked as unstable, which is likely causing the entire `MessageView` composable to be recomposed whenever the `ApiManagementFragment` value changes, even if `ApiManagementFragment` is not used directly within `MessageView`.

When a composable function in Compose contains an unstable argument (a parameter whose value can change throughout recompositions), the Compose framework designates the composable as "not skippable." This means that whenever the value of the unstable parameter changes, even if the composable itself doesn't directly use that value, it will be recomposed.

Comment: I know that: if you pass an unstable parameter to a composable function, it make the function un skippable , but my question is why android passes the fragment as a parameter to my composables?